# couchdb -gt: unexpected operator

Tags: bash, service, couchdb, ubuntu-14.04

Trying to start CouchDB with this command

```
sudo service couchdb start
```

or with this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb start
```

on Ubuntu Server 14.04 both commands fails with this error:

```
sudo service couchdb start

* Starting database server couchdb
/usr/local/bin/couchdb: 214: test: -gt: unexpected operator
                                                             [ OK ]
```

I took a look in this couchdb wiki https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Error_messages
but could not find an answer, neither in previous questions 
at stackoverflow.

The code in file /usr/local/bin/couchdb at line 214 is this:

```
if test `echo 2> /dev/null >> $PID_FILE; echo $?` -gt 0; then
    echo "$message_prefix PID file: $PID_FILE" >&2
    false
fi
```

The CouchDB version is

```
$ sudo couchdb -V
couchdb - Apache CouchDB 1.6.1
```

Comment: That error seems to indicate that `echo 2> /dev/null >> $PID_FILE; echo $?` failed to return a value correctly or returned too many values. I'm not sure how either of those is possible exactly but that's a poorly written test in any case.

Comment: Seems like something you could rewrite which may solve your issue. Not sure exactly what that snippet is trying to accomplish though

Comment: From where do you got file `/usr/local/bin/couchdb`? If I install package "couchdb" (`sudo apt-get install couchdb`) in Ubuntu 14.04.1 all works fine and directory "/usr/local/bin" is empty.

Comment: @Cyrus the same ask my self, the couchdb installation was done by other person so I don't know how couchdb was installed.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! well the problem was that couchdb databases was taking to much disk space and was almost full of space, and some compaction fail to process ... causing couchdb to stop working and when trying to start don't find enough disk space to work